# Search Linkedin by single string?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, url, linkedin-api

How to search [LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/) with a single string? My problem is that i have **single name field in database**... Normaly one would create dynamic url like this:

```
http://www.linkedin.com/pub/dir/?first=John&last=Doe&search=Search
```

and LinkedIn returns all John Doe's as a result. My question is, is there a way to make a search by single string? Something like:

```
http://www.linkedin.com/pub/dir/?keyword=John%20Doe&search=Search
```

I need a direct url implementation for my web, not the `api.linkedin`, so my example in *mvc3 razor* would be something like:

```
foreach(var item in Model.People)
{
    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/dir/?keyword="+
        item.Name +"&search=Search">item.Name</>
}
```

Is this aproach possible, or I need to use api. I have noticed that when you login to LinkedIn, there is a search by one string in upper right corner. Does normal(anonymus) version of web have this posibility??

Comment: The search indicator you mentioned leads to "http://www.linkedin.com/search/fpsearch?type=people&keywords=somenamehere". You could  use this for your hrefs. But when you click this link linkedin forces you to login anyway and then leads you to the search results page.

Comment: @ryadavilli, it has to be public, otherwise i need to use api.

Comment: This public URL might work for you.  [http://in.linkedin.com/pub/dir/?first=John&last=&search=Search]. This displays the search results but clicking on profiles will then force a login/register.

Comment: @ryadavilli, i do not need search by first and last name, i need a search by single string that contains first and last name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following:

`http://www.linkedin.com/ta/federator?query=example&types=mynetwork,company,group,sitefeature,skill`

This will give you a result set in JSON

Comment: tnx, but i need a url that will return list of LinkedIn users in LinkedIn gui. Same as already exists with FirstName,LastName query.

Comment: Is this a supported API? I can't seem to find any official reference to it, this forum posts indicates it is not
http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/2970

Comment: @Marc I don't think its an actual "supported API", but its the same API the linkedin front end uses to show search results while you type, at the front page.